# html2pdf fit image to pdf

Tags: resize, jspdf, html2canvas, html2pdf

I finally got my html2pdf to work showing my web page just how I want it in the pdf(Any other size was not showing right so I kept adjusting the format size until it all fit properly), and the end result is exactly what I want it to look like... EXCEPT even though my aspect ratio is correct for a landscape, it is still using a very large image and the pdf is not standard letter size (Or a4 for that matter), it is the size I set.  This makes for a larger pdf than necessary and does not print well unless we adjust it for the printer.  I basically want this exact image just converted to a a4 or letter size to make a smaller pdf.  If I don't use the size I set though things are cut off.

Anyway to take this pdf that is generated and resize to be an a4 size(Still fitting the image on it).  Everything I try is not working, and I feel like I am missing something simple.

```
 const el = document.getElementById("test);
    var opt = {
      margin: [10, 10, 10, 10],
      filename: label,
      image: { type: "jpeg", quality: 0.98 },
      //pagebreak: { mode: ["avoid-all", "css"], after: ".newPage" },
      pagebreak: {
        mode: ["css"],
        avoid: ["tr"],
        //    mode: ["legacy"],
        after: ".newPage",
        before: ".newPrior"
      },
      /*pagebreak: {
      before: ".newPage",
      avoid: ["h2", "tr", "h3", "h4", ".field"]
    },*/
      html2canvas: {
        scale: 2,
        logging: true,
        dpi: 192,
        letterRendering: true
      },
      jsPDF: {
        unit: "mm",
        format: [463, 600],
        orientation: "landscape"
      }
    };

   
      var doc = html2pdf()
     
        .from(el)
        .set(opt)
        .toContainer()
        .toCanvas()
        .toImg()
        .toPdf()
         .save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this a lot as well. In the end I was able to resolve the issue for me. What did the trick for me was setting the `width`-property in `html2canvas`. My application has a fixed width, and setting the width of `html2canvas` to the width of my application, scaled the PDF to fit on an A4 paper.

```
html2canvas: { width: element_width},
```

Try adding the above option to see if it works. Try to find out the width of your print area in pixels and replace `element_width` with that width.

For completeness: I am using [Plotly Dash](https://plotly.com/dash/) to create web user interfaces. On my interface I include a button that when clicked generates a PDF report of my dashboard. Below I added the code that I used for this, in case anybody is looking for a Dash solution. To get this working in Dash, download [html2pdf.bundlemin.js](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js/tree/master/dist) and copy it to the `assets/` folder. The PDF file will be downloaded to the browsers default downloads folder (it might give a download prompt, however that wasn't how it worked for me).

```py
from dash import html, clientside_callback
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

# Define your Dash app in the regular way

# In the layout define a component that will trigger the download of the 
# PDF report. In this example a button will be responsible.
app.layout = html.Div(
    id='main_container',
    children = [
        dbc.Button(
            id='button_download_report',
            children='Download PDF report',
            className='me-1')
     ])

# Clientside callbacks allow you to directly insert Javascript code in your
# dashboards. There are also other ways, like including your own js files
# in the assets/ directory.  
clientside_callback(
    '''
    function (button_clicked) {
        if (button_clicked > 0) {
            // Get the element that you want to print. In this example the 
            // whole dashboard is printed
            var element = document.getElementById("main_container")

            // create a date-time string to use for the filename
            const d = new Date();
            var month = (d.getMonth() + 1).toString()
            if (month.length == 1) {
                month = "0" + month
            }
            let text = d.getFullYear().toString() + month + d.getDay() + '-' + d.getHours() + d.getMinutes();

            // Set the options to be used when printing the PDF
            var main_container_width = element.style.width;
            var opt = {
                margin: 10,
                filename: text + '_my-dashboard.pdf',
                image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
                html2canvas: { scale: 3, width: main_container_width, dpi: 300 },
                jsPDF: { unit: 'mm', format: 'A4', orientation: 'p' },
                // Set pagebreaks if you like. It didn't work out well for me.
                // pagebreak: { mode: ['avoid-all'] }
            };
            // Execute the save command. 
            html2pdf().from(element).set(opt).save();
        }
    }
    ''',
    Output(component_id='button_download_report', component_property='n_clicks'),
    Input(component_id='button_download_report', component_property='n_clicks')
)
```